# Getting this error in facebook (com.facebook.error.2 )

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios7

I am using the Facebook graph Api in my application. I was getting this error . In Facebook developer while create the application account we has given the same bundle identifier which is given in the application, still i face the problem. I was facing the issue because in iPhone we are having two types of login one is through Go to Setting --> add your account credentials , second is login through the Facebook api . Now if i want to open the Facebook then i am getting this error.If i delete the account from the setting screen then my Facebook sdk is working. Waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Turns out: a com.facebook.sdk error 2 can translate into a number of things. I'm looking for some kind of Facebook SDK error translation table, but I'm unable to find one. In my case: **The com.facebook.sdk error 2 happened because the connection timed out. Users who got this error had a bad network/WiFi connection.**

We implemented an error logging system, which logged the error details every time an error happened while logging into Facebook. In those logs we could see a com.facebook.sdk error 2 happening quite a lot, but it being resolved every time the user tried to log in again after a few seconds.

It might be due to my inability to find the right documentation, but I was and still am quite frustrated about the vagueness of these SDK errors. There is a lot of documentation about permission asking (which can result into the com.facebook.sdk error 2), but apparently this error can be caused by more things. It would be nice to see this documented somewhere as well.

**AND OTHER WAY.....**

This happened for an app that I was using. I was able to get around it by going to my iPhone settings, selecting Facebook, tapping on my name, and clicking "delete account."

Afterwards I was able to sign in with the app without issue.

I went back to settings | facebook and resubmitted my credentials.

The app still works fine.
```

Comment: Delete an account is working fine but i cant able say to user to delete the account from the settings. I am finding for this problem.Thanx for reply @AppleMap